# Missing plus sign and brackets inside equation

Tags: equations, symbols, compilation-error

I'm using a template with the following packages:

```
\documentclass{osa-article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\journal{osac}
```

The compilation of the following equation does supress the `plus` sign.
Also, brackets are only displayed with `\left(` and `\right)`. Using only simple brackets like  `"("` or `")"` would supressed the brackets also

```
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{total} \left(T\right)  =   \epsilon_{nAirl} \left(T,P, ...\right) + \epsilon_{expansion 1} \left(T\right)  + \epsilon_{expansion 2}\left (T\right)  +    \epsilon_{Laser} \left(T,P,...\right)  + ... 
\end{equation} \label{Tequa}
```

My operating system is Windows 10 and i'm using MikTeX 21.3
A colleague tried complilation on his computer with with windows 10 and TechMaker with the same result.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: Is the `osa-article` document class availabe online somewhere?

Comment: I would guess you need to remove `lmodern` (although untested as I don't have the class) don't change the font setup in a journal supplied class, the whole point of the class is to enforce a house style.

Comment: Thanks.
This is the solution.
The package lmodern is in conflict with something else
Without all the signs appear

Answer (score 3):

The `osa-article` class does

```
\RequirePackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,courier}
\RequirePackage{helvet}
```

and loading `lmodern` after the class will produce weird output, because of conflicts in definition of math symbols.

On the other hand, the OSA wants that papers have a uniform appearance (notwithstanding that the choice of the sans serif and monospaced fonts is disputable), so no font package should be loaded in the document.

Comment: Someone should tell OSA not to load `helvet` after `newtx`...

Comment: @campa At least, to load it with a reduced size.